# Autocorrelation function of phase modulated wiener process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, correlation

How to find the autocorrelation function $R_x(\tau)=E[X(t_1)X^*(t_2)]$ of phase modulated Winner random process oscillation $X\left( t \right)=\exp \left\{ j\varphi \left( t \right) \right\}$, where $\varphi \left( t \right)=2\pi \int\limits_{0}^{t}{\dot{n}\left( u \right)du}$?
And how to find ACF ${{R}_{y}}\left( {{\tau }_{1}} \right)$ of process $Y\left( t,{{\tau }_{1}} \right)=X\left( t \right){{X}^{*}}\left( t+{{\tau }_{1}} \right)$, which is a signal at the output of the RF downconverted mixer to the first input of which the signal $X(t)$ is being sent, and to the second one its delayed copy for a while $\tau_1$ ?

Comment: You meant $\varphi(t)$ is a Wiener process ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Yes   φ(t) is a Wiener process. I know that the correlation function $R_x(\tau)$  equals to $\exp \left( -{{{\sigma }^{2}}\left| \tau  \right|}/{2}\; \right)$, but i dont know how that eqution is obtained.I'm interested in the order of its output for obtaining an expression for $R_y(\tau_1)$

Comment: What is the result we are supposed to obtain for $E[X(t+a) X(t)^*]$ ? I'm not sure but won't we have $E[(X(t+a)-X(t)) X(t)^*] = 0$ thus $E[X(t+a) X(t)^*] = E[X(t) X(t)^*]$.

Comment: $E[(X(t+a)-X(t)) X(t)^*] =E[(e^{i (\varphi(t+a)-\varphi(t))}-1) X(t) X(t)^*] = 0$ because $e^{i (\varphi(t+a)-\varphi(t))}-1, X(t) X(t)^*$ are independent and the former is zero-mean.

Comment: I know that φ(t) is bandlimited Gaussian noise. Badwidh is proportional of variance of n(t) and correlation time is inverse proportional of BW. I think if $a=0$, then $E[X(t+a)X(t)^*]=1$,  and if $a->inf$, then $E[X(t+a)X(t)]=0$. I would like to find of functioal relation $R_x(a)$ for future PSD calculation.

Comment: I think I just proved $E[X(t+a) X(t)^*] = E[X(t) X(t)^*] = 1$ for every $a \ge 0$